# Command Line Prompt on wrong place of screen

Tags: terminal, manjaro, i3

I recently installed Manjaro Linux with i3wm on my PC. But ever since I updated my system the command prompt line shows up halfway down the screen of the i3-sensible terminal (it might also have happened after I had to change some settings due to my hidpi-screen).
I have read in other threads that the "reset" command or pressing ctrl+l might help, but both only work temporarily until I close the terminal.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated!
[image]

My bashrc and .profile files:

bashrc:

```
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

colors() {
    local fgc bgc vals seq0

    printf "Color escapes are %s\n" '\e[${value};...;${value}m'
    printf "Values 30..37 are \e[33mforeground colors\e[m\n"
    printf "Values 40..47 are \e[43mbackground colors\e[m\n"
    printf "Value  1 gives a  \e[1mbold-faced look\e[m\n\n"

    # foreground colors
    for fgc in {30..37}; do
        # background colors
        for bgc in {40..47}; do
            fgc=${fgc#37} # white
            bgc=${bgc#40} # black

            vals="${fgc:+$fgc;}${bgc}"
            vals=${vals%%;}

            seq0="${vals:+\e[${vals}m}"
            printf "  %-9s" "${seq0:-(default)}"
            printf " ${seq0}TEXT\e[m"
            printf " \e[${vals:+${vals+$vals;}}1mBOLD\e[m"
        done
        echo; echo
    done
}

[ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ] && . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion

# Change the window title of X terminals
case ${TERM} in
    xterm*|rxvt*|Eterm*|aterm|kterm|gnome*|interix|konsole*)
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/\~}\007"'
        ;;
    screen*)
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033_${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/\~}\033\\"'
        ;;
esac

use_color=true

# Set colorful PS1 only on colorful terminals.
# dircolors --print-database uses its own built-in database
# instead of using /etc/DIR_COLORS.  Try to use the external file
# first to take advantage of user additions.  Use internal bash
# globbing instead of external grep binary.
safe_term=${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/?}   # sanitize TERM
match_lhs=""
[[ -f ~/.dir_colors   ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(<~/.dir_colors)"
[[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(</etc/DIR_COLORS)"
[[ -z ${match_lhs}    ]] \
    && type -P dircolors >/dev/null \
    && match_lhs=$(dircolors --print-database)
[[ $'\n'${match_lhs} == *$'\n'"TERM "${safe_term}* ]] && use_color=true

if ${use_color} ; then
    # Enable colors for ls, etc.  Prefer ~/.dir_colors #64489
    if type -P dircolors >/dev/null ; then
        if [[ -f ~/.dir_colors ]] ; then
            eval $(dircolors -b ~/.dir_colors)
        elif [[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] ; then
            eval $(dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS)
        fi
    fi

    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        PS1='[user1@\w]$ '             
    else
        PS1='[user1@\w]$ '                      
    fi

    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias grep='grep --colour=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --colour=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --colour=auto'
else
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        # show root@ when we don't have colors
        PS1='\u@\h \W \$ '
    else
        PS1='\u@\h \w \$ '
    fi
fi

unset use_color safe_term match_lhs sh

#alias cp="cp -i"                          # confirm before overwriting something
#alias df='df -h'                          # human-readable sizes
#alias free='free -m'                      # show sizes in MB
#alias np='nano -w PKGBUILD'
#alias more=less

xhost +local:root > /dev/null 2>&1

# Bash won't get SIGWINCH if another process is in the foreground.
# Enable checkwinsize so that bash will check the terminal size when
# it regains control.  #65623
# http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/~chet/bash/FAQ (E11)
shopt -s checkwinsize

shopt -s expand_aliases

# export QT_SELECT=4

# Enable history appending instead of overwriting.  #139609
shopt -s histappend

#
# # ex - archive extractor
# # usage: ex <file>
ex ()
{
  if [ -f $1 ] ; then
    case $1 in
      *.tar.bz2)   tar xjf $1   ;;
      *.tar.gz)    tar xzf $1   ;;
      *.bz2)       bunzip2 $1   ;;
      *.rar)       unrar x $1     ;;
      *.gz)        gunzip $1    ;;
      *.tar)       tar xf $1    ;;
      *.tbz2)      tar xjf $1   ;;
      *.tgz)       tar xzf $1   ;;
      *.zip)       unzip $1     ;;
      *.Z)         uncompress $1;;
      *.7z)        7z x $1      ;;
      *)           echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via ex()" ;;
    esac
  else
    echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
  fi
}
```

.profile:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
export GTK2_RC_FILES="$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0"
# fix "xdg-open fork-bomb" export your preferred browser from here
export BROWSER=/usr/bin/palemoon
```

Also when I use xterm, the prompt is where it should be.

Comment: When you run commands and get to the bottom of the screen and keep going, does scrolling text move into the upper section of the screen? Or is the prompt (as shown) at the top of the scrolling section?

Comment: It then moves to the upper section, same thing when I use "clear"

Comment: Silly question: is there something new in your shell's initialisation file (e.g. `.bashrc` or `.profile` or `.bash_profile` for `bash`) that's moving the cursor?

Comment: I have just checked those, it doesn't seem so to me (though I'm kind of a noob :))

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification instead of using comments for this purpose. Can you try the same in other terminal emulations like `xterm`?  What happens when you change the size of the terminal window? If you are unsure about .`bashrc` or `.profile` you could paste the contents of these files *as text* to your question, formatted as code blocks.